# Undesirable offest in sub-menu when parent menu items are skewed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu

Basically, I have a plugin for generating "full-width" mega menu, in addition, menu items are transformed using CSS3 2D transformation:

```
ul.menu {
     transform: skewX(-30deg);
}

ul.menu > li > ul.sub-menu {
    /* Do not skew sub menus */
    transform: skewX(30deg);
}
```

The problem is that different sub items have undesirable offset, and I want to fix it.

The bug can be seene here: https://gyazo.com/d2ab34232904c750fc5e2a59a2807f8d

FYI, the plugin uses JS to determine the absolute position of sub menus, so my idea is to use `margin-left` property t o adjust the position, but it's not working as expected.

```
$('.fmm-main > li').each(function() {
        var degrees = 30;

        var item = $(this);
        var menu = item.parent();
        var subm = item.children('ul');

        if(!subm.length) return;

        // Convert degrees to radians.
        var menu_radians = degrees * (Math.PI / 180);
        var subm_radians = (degrees / 2) * (Math.PI / 180);

        var menu_h = parseInt(menu.css('height'), 10);
        var subm_h = parseInt(subm.css('height'), 10);

        // We need to factor these in to get an accurate offset.
        subm_h += parseInt(item.css('height'), 10);
        subm_h += parseInt(item.css('padding-top'), 10);
        subm_h += parseInt(item.css('padding-bottom'), 10);
        subm_h += parseInt(subm.css('top'), 10);

        // Get skew offsets.
        var menu_offset = menu_h * Math.atan(menu_radians);
        var subm_offset = subm_h * Math.atan(subm_radians);

        // Put everything together.
        var offset = (subm_offset - menu_offset);

        subm.css('marginLeft', offset);

    });
```

Any suggestins?

Comment: Could you provide a minimal working example in a code snippet? It is hard to see where the problem is without the HTML and CSS.

Comment: Looking at the screencap you provided, it looks to me like you could position the submenu absolutely and get rid of these calculations all together. Any reason you are not doing that?

Comment: Have a look at this, it might help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin .... I guess you need it left aligned instead of the default centered

Comment: Thanks! Actually, it's a premium WP plugin, so it's not that easy to create a fiddle. Anyway, you can see the testing environment here: http://www.wotta.com/jq-wp/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure where you want your menus to align so let me know if things need to be shifted a bit.

Using your current design, try this CSS:

```
ul.menu {
     transform: skewX(-30deg);
     transform-origin: 0 50%;
}

ul.menu > li > ul.sub-menu {
    /* Do not skew sub menus */
    transform: skewX(30deg);
     transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

The menus will then live at a fixed position even with the edge of your page and the skewed menu is centered on the page.